# ¿Cómo excluir GROUP BY de un LEFT JOIN en específico?

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Estoy conectando una tabla llamada `tbl_order` por el código del producto: `code_unique`, el objetivo de esta tabla es sumar las ventas realizadas de ese producto, por ejemplo tengo 100 registros que se han vendido, no quiero imprimir 100 registros solo quiero un registro contabilizando las sumas totales de ese producto vendido que exactamente está en la columna `quantity`.

El problema es que en la tabla `tbl_stock` estoy sumando todos los registros repetidos agrupando o por condición de `GROUP BY`, hasta allí, esta funcionando perfectamente. El único detalle es que si yo solo tengo 4 ventas realizadas de `x` producto en la consulta me está duplicando ese valor en vez de mostrar `4` que es lo correcto, me muestra `8` valor incorrecto.

Esta es mi consulta:

```
SELECT sp.id_stock_product,
    ent.establishment,
    bo.establishment,
    ent.tradename,
    bo.tradename,
    sp.code_unique,
    sp.model,
    sp.size,
    sp.color,
    SUM(sp.item_total) as item_total,
    SUM(odr.quantity) as total_sales
FROM tbl_stock_product sp
LEFT JOIN tbl_access ac ON sp.id_enterprise = ac.id_enterprise OR sp.id_branch_office = ac.id_branch_office
LEFT JOIN tbl_enterprise ent ON sp.id_enterprise = ent.id_enterprise
LEFT JOIN tbl_branch_office bo ON sp.id_branch_office = bo.id_branch_office
LEFT JOIN tbl_order odr ON sp.code_unique = odr.code_unique AND sp.id_enterprise = odr.id_enterprise OR sp.id_branch_office = odr.id_branch_office
WHERE ac.id_user = 2
GROUP BY sp.id_enterprise, sp.id_branch_office, sp.code_unique, sp.model, sp.size, sp.color DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

¿Cómo evito que estos valores se dupliquen en esta columna específicamente `SUM(odr.quantity) AS total_sales`?

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

---

Tablas registradas en el siguiente compilador online:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q3iEtNW28frgwETSgVV6ZQ/0

En un resumen esto sería los datos correctos esperados:

| code_unique | model | size | color | item_total | total_sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HOLA | null | null | null | 2010 | 4 |

> Nota: excluí en el ejemplo las demás tablas, no quiere decir que no la este utilizando, pero para ser precisos en los resultados esperados agregue solo estas columnas aquí SO.

Comment: Los duplicados pueden darse si una de las tablas de la relación contiene dos registros que coincidan con el criterio del join.

Comment: @Lobos tengo que hacer una subconsulta, o que alternativas puedo realizar  ya que la `tbl_order` es necesaria para saber cuántos productos se han vendido y posteriormente determinar cuántos productos tengo en stock (disponibles).

Comment: @Lobos Cabe recalcar que la suma de los productos repetidos solo lo estoy haciendo de la tabla `tbl_stock` la misma que se puede observar en `GROUP BY`

Comment: Es complicado encontrar la respuesta sin conocer las tablas y los datos. ¿Podrías agregar un script con tablas y datos para reproducir el escenario?

Comment: Hay una relacion 1XN entre algunas de esas tablas... sin saber donde esta esa relacion, dificil darte una solucion...

Comment: @gbianchi Hola agregue los datos en el siguiente compilador: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q3iEtNW28frgwETSgVV6ZQ/0

Comment: @Lobos  Hola agregue los datos en el siguiente compilador: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q3iEtNW28frgwETSgVV6ZQ/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La tabla `tbl_stock_product` tiene estos datos:

| id_stock_product | id_enterprise | id_branch_office | code_unique | item_total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | 1 | HOLA | 1000 |
| 2 | NULL | 1 | HOLA | 10 |
| 3 | NULL | 1 | HOLA | 1000 |

Y la tabla `tbl_order` tiene estos datos:

| id_manage_order | id_branch_office | id_enterprise | code_unique | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | NULL | HOLA | 1 |
| 2 | NULL | 1 | HOLA | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | NULL | HOLA | 2 |
| 4 | 1 | NULL | HOLA | 1 |
| 5 | NULL | 1 | HOLA | 1 |

Al hacer el `join` entre las dos tablas:

```
SELECT sp.id_stock_product,
       sp.code_unique,
       sp.item_total,
       odr.quantity
FROM tbl_stock_product sp
         LEFT JOIN tbl_order odr ON sp.code_unique = odr.code_unique AND sp.id_enterprise = odr.id_enterprise OR
                                    sp.id_branch_office = odr.id_branch_office
```

El resultado es este:

| id_stock_product | code_unique | item_total | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | HOLA | 1000 | 1 |
| 1 | HOLA | 1000 | 2 |
| 1 | HOLA | 1000 | 1 |
| 2 | HOLA | 10 | 1 |
| 2 | HOLA | 10 | 2 |
| 2 | HOLA | 10 | 1 |
| 3 | HOLA | 1000 | 1 |
| 3 | HOLA | 1000 | 2 |
| 3 | HOLA | 1000 | 1 |

El resultado anterior está correcto ya que se observa que por cada registro de la tabla `tbl_stock_product` hay tres registros que coinciden en la tabla `tbl_order`.

Para llegar al resultado esperado se puede hacer en dos pasos:

1. Sumar la columna  `quantity` y crear una partición por el campo `id_stock_product` para tomar un valor único por cada grupo.
2. Tomar la consulta anterior y usarla como subconsulta, luego agrupar de nuevo, esta vez sumando el campo `item_total`.

### Paso 1

```
SELECT sp.id_stock_product,
                sp.code_unique,
                sp.model,
                sp.size,
                sp.color,
                max(sp.item_total) over (partition by id_stock_product) as item_total,
                sum(odr.quantity)                                       as quantity
         FROM tbl_stock_product sp
                  LEFT JOIN tbl_access ac
                            ON sp.id_enterprise = ac.id_enterprise OR sp.id_branch_office = ac.id_branch_office
                  LEFT JOIN tbl_enterprise ent ON sp.id_enterprise = ent.id_enterprise
                  LEFT JOIN tbl_branch_office bo ON sp.id_branch_office = bo.id_branch_office
                  left JOIN tbl_order odr
                            ON sp.code_unique = odr.code_unique AND (sp.id_branch_office = odr.id_branch_office)
         WHERE ac.id_user = 2
         GROUP BY sp.code_unique, sp.model, sp.size, sp.color, sp.id_stock_product, sp.item_total
```

El resultado es este:

| id_stock_product | code_unique | model | size | color | item_total | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | HOLA | NULL | NULL | NULL | 1000 | 4 |
| 2 | HOLA | NULL | NULL | NULL | 10 | 4 |
| 3 | HOLA | NULL | NULL | NULL | 1000 | 4 |

Ya quedó resuelta  la columna `quantity`.

### Paso 2

```
select
       t.code_unique,
       t.model,
       t.size,
       t.color,
       sum(t.item_total) as item_total,
       t.quantity
from (
         SELECT sp.id_stock_product,
                sp.code_unique,
                sp.model,
                sp.size,
                sp.color,
                max(sp.item_total) over (partition by id_stock_product) as item_total,
                sum(odr.quantity)                                       as quantity
         FROM tbl_stock_product sp
                  LEFT JOIN tbl_access ac
                            ON sp.id_enterprise = ac.id_enterprise OR sp.id_branch_office = ac.id_branch_office
                  LEFT JOIN tbl_enterprise ent ON sp.id_enterprise = ent.id_enterprise
                  LEFT JOIN tbl_branch_office bo ON sp.id_branch_office = bo.id_branch_office
                  left JOIN tbl_order odr
                            ON sp.code_unique = odr.code_unique AND (sp.id_branch_office = odr.id_branch_office)
         WHERE ac.id_user = 2
         GROUP BY sp.code_unique, sp.model, sp.size, sp.color, sp.id_stock_product, sp.item_total
     ) t
group by t.code_unique, t.model, t.size, t.color, t.quantity;
```

Resultado:

| code_unique | model | size | color | item_total | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HOLA | NULL | NULL | NULL | 2010 | 4 |

Comment: Amigo necesito ayuda por favor, si recuerdas que he comentado que las ventas pueden ser de empresa o de sucursal y otra cosa que me di cuenta es que también debo agregar en la tabla `tbl_order` las columnas de `model, size, color` porque si no las agrego al momento de insertar un nuevo registros en la tabla `tbl_stock_product` con el mismo código `HOLA` pero esta vez agregando `size` o `color` este me esta diciendo que se han vendido 4 productos esto fue antes de agregar las nuevas columnas a `tbl_order` viendo este error agregue esas columnas pero me esta diciendo lo mismo

Comment: Es decir que el código `HOLA` con talla `M` y color `NEGRO` se han vendido `4` cuando ahora con los nuevos registros solo están ventas del mismo código pero solo con talla `X` o `XL`. Aquí actualice el código amigo https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q3iEtNW28frgwETSgVV6ZQ/1 ayúdame por favor. intente agregando lo siguiente `ON sp.code_unique = odr.code_unique
     AND (sp.id_enterprise = odr.id_enterprise)
     OR (sp.id_branch_office = odr.id_branch_office)
     AND (sp.model = odr.model)
     AND (sp.size = odr.size)
     AND (sp.color = odr.color)`  pero no funciona

Comment: otra cosa que me di cuenta es que cuando no existen ventas realizadas de dicho producto: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q3iEtNW28frgwETSgVV6ZQ/3 en `t.quantity` no imprime nada, lo ideal sería mostrar `0`

Comment: Mejor publique una nueva pregunta dando todos los detalles del problema https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/562520/error-en-la-cantidad-de-productos-vendidos-y-resultado-incorrecto-de-stock-dispo

Comment: Mejor publique una nueva pregunta dando todos los detalles del problema https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/562520/error-en-la-cantidad-de-productos-vendidos-y-resultado-incorrecto-de-stock-dispo