# Error en la cantidad de productos vendidos y resultado incorrecto de stock disponible en MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Estas son las tablas más importantes para obtener el resultado deseado:

Registros: `tbl_order`

| id_order | id_enterprise | id_branch_office | code_unique | title_product | model | size | color | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | 1 | HOLA | null | null | X | null | 10 |
| 2 | null | 1 | HOLA | null | null | XL | null | 3 |
| 3 | null | 1 | HOLA | null | null | null | RED | 3 |
| 4 | 1 | null | HOLA | null | null | null | RED | 3 |

Registros: `tbl_stock_product`

| id_stock_product | id_enterprise | id_branch_office | code_unique | title_product | model | size | color | item_total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | 1 | HOLA | null | null | X | null | 100 |
| 2 | null | 1 | HOLA | null | null | X | null | 1000 |
| 3 | null | 1 | HOLA | null | null | XL | null | 500 |
| 4 | null | 1 | HOLA | null | null | null | RED | 10 |
| 4 | null | 1 | HOL | MDLX1 | null | null | null | 300 |

Cabe señalar que las columnas `model, size, color` pueden estar con datos o vacías dependiendo del tipo de producto. Lo que si se requiere es el código único del producto (`code_unique`) y a quién pertenece ese producto, aquí deber ser solo uno empresa( `id_enterprise`) o sucursal(`id_branch_office`).

Con la siguiente consulta lo he logrado casi todo, el único problema es `total_sales` y `stock` que son los `AS` que están en el primer `SELECT` de la consulta:

```
SELECT t.enterprise_establishment,
        t.office_establishment,
        t.enterprise_tradename,
        t.office_tradename,
        t.code_unique,
        t.model,
        t.size,
        t.color,
        SUM(t.item_total) AS item_total,
        t.quantity AS  total_sales,
        SUM(t.item_total) - t.quantity AS stock
        FROM (
            SELECT sp.id_stock_product,
                ent.establishment AS enterprise_establishment,
                bo.establishment AS office_establishment,
                ent.tradename AS enterprise_tradename,
                bo.tradename AS office_tradename,
                sp.code_unique,
                sp.model,
                sp.size,
                sp.color,
                max(sp.item_total) over (PARTITION BY id_stock_product) AS item_total,
                SUM(odr.quantity) AS quantity
            FROM tbl_stock_product sp
                LEFT JOIN tbl_access ac
                    ON sp.id_enterprise = ac.id_enterprise OR sp.id_branch_office = ac.id_branch_office
                LEFT JOIN tbl_enterprise ent ON sp.id_enterprise = ent.id_enterprise
                LEFT JOIN tbl_branch_office bo ON sp.id_branch_office = bo.id_branch_office
                LEFT JOIN tbl_order odr
                    ON sp.code_unique = odr.code_unique
                    AND (sp.id_enterprise = odr.id_enterprise OR sp.id_branch_office = odr.id_branch_office)
                    AND sp.model = odr.model
                    AND sp.size = odr.size
                    AND sp.color = odr.color
                WHERE ac.id_user = 2
                GROUP BY sp.code_unique, sp.model, sp.size, sp.color, sp.id_stock_product, sp.item_total
        ) t
    GROUP BY t.code_unique, t.model, t.size, t.color, t.quantity
```

Los problemas:

- `t.quantity AS  total_sales`:

  - Está restando las ventas a todos los resultados de la tabla `tbl_stock_product`, a pesar de tener una talla, color o modelo diferente.
  - Cuando no hay registros de ventas en la tabla `tbl_order`, no muestra nada, lo ideal sería mostrar 0.
- `SUM(t.item_total) - t.quantity AS stock`:

  - Cuando no hay registros de ventas en la tabla `tbl_order`, no muestra nada, lo ideal sería volver a mostrar el total de productos disponibles así como `SUM(t.item_total) AS item_total` eje: `300 productos disponibles` `-` `0 ventas` `=` `300`.

Lo que está afectando o generando este problema son las siguientes condiciones pasadas a la tabla `tbl_order`:

```
            LEFT JOIN tbl_order odr
                ON sp.code_unique = odr.code_unique
                AND (sp.id_enterprise = odr.id_enterprise OR sp.id_branch_office = odr.id_branch_office)
                AND sp.model = odr.model
                AND sp.size = odr.size
                AND sp.color = odr.color
```

Investigando encontré lo siguiente: MySQL no podrá distinguir entre una columna que es `NULL` considerando aquello intente con lo siguiente, pero sigo teniendo el mismo problema:

```
            LEFT JOIN tbl_order odr
                ON sp.code_unique = odr.code_unique
                AND (sp.id_enterprise = odr.id_enterprise OR sp.id_branch_office = odr.id_branch_office)
                AND ((sp.model IS NULL OR odr.model IS NULL) OR sp.model = odr.model)
                AND ((sp.size IS NULL OR odr.size IS NULL) OR sp.size = odr.size)
                AND ((sp.color IS NULL OR odr.color IS NULL) OR sp.color = odr.color)
```

Resultado deseado:

| code_unique | model | size | color | item_total | total_sales | stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HOLA | null | X | null | 1100 | 10 | 1090 |
| HOLA | null | XL | null | 500 | 3 | 497 |
| HOLA | null | null | RED | 10 | 3 | 7 |
| HOL | null | null | null | 300 | 0 | 300 |

Prueba en compilador online: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q3iEtNW28frgwETSgVV6ZQ/3

Pregunta anterior:

[¿Cómo excluir GROUP BY de un LEFT JOIN en específico?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/562241/c%c3%b3mo-excluir-group-by-de-un-left-join-en-espec%c3%adfico)

> Nota: En la pregunta anterior se había comentado que el objetivo era obtener un inventario y, me di cuenta que necesitaba también agregar otras columnas a la tabla `tbl_order` que no era suficiente con la columna `code_unique` ya que con esa tabla no se va ha saber cuantos productos `x` con talla o color o modelo fueron vendidos.

Comment: Tu db fiddle tiene un error de compilación, no se puede testear.

Comment: @Sr1871 Hola, si se dice que el error es por esto `max(sp.item_total) over (PARTITION BY id_stock_product) AS item_total` pero en mi versión 5.2.0 no me genera ese error

Comment: @Sr1871 Hola, si se dice que el error es por esto `max(sp.item_total) over (PARTITION BY id_stock_product) AS item_total` pero en mi versión 5.2.0 no me genera ese error

Comment: El modelo de las tablas se me hace extraño. `tbl_stock_product` debería tener los datos de: size, model, color, etc... y `tbl_order` debería hacer relación usando el campo `tbl_stock_product.id_stock_product`, eso simplificaría mucho la consulta. Podrías probar haciendo ese cambio.

Comment: @Lobos Lo que pasa es que solo estoy usando una sola tabla es decir `tbl_stock_product` para todo tipo de productos, por ejemplo si es un producto digital no tendría `model, size, color` solo sería código único de ese servicio. Otro ejemplo un producto que puede tener modelo pero no `size, color`. Lo estoy usando así para no crear una tabla para productos digitales, otra tabla para servicios, otra tabla para modelo y color, otra tabla para talla, color. Entonces por eso estoy usando una sola tabla para no crear más y, simplemente al momento de ingresar los datos creo un formulario según el...

Comment: @Lobos el tipo de producto así no muestro otros formularios pero ya a la hora de imprimir todos los resultados allí si refleja toda la información como se encuentra en la última tabla `Resultado deseado:`

Comment: @Lobos Por eso entonces pensé que el problema sería por algunas columnas `NULL` pero al agregar estas condiciones `AND ((sp.model IS NULL OR odr.model IS NULL) OR sp.model = odr.model)` sigue siendo el mismo problema.

Comment: Lo que entiendo es que `tbl_stock_product` sirve como tabla genérica para guardar distintas configuraciones de productos y por eso algunos campos quedan en `null`. Entonces el `id_stock_product = 1` es una configuración, el `2` es otra configuración, y la tabla `tbl_order` lleva el registro de cuántas ventas se han hecho de cada configuración. Si es así, `tbl_order` no necesita saber los detalles de la configuración porque ya están contenidos en `tbl_stock_product`. Has la prueba agregando la relación con el campo `tbl_stock_product.id_stock_product`, pienso que debería funcionar.

Comment: @Lobos Si amigo la tabla `tbl_stock_product` sirve  para guardar distintas configuraciones de productos y, exactamente en algunas ocasiones algunos campos van a quedar en `null` y si la tabla `tbl_order` es para saber cuantos productos se han vendido tomando en cuenta los siguientes parámetros uno de estos `id`: `id_enterprise` o `id_branch_office`  y lo demás `code_unique, model, size, color`.

Comment: @Lobos Así como puede observar en el resultado deseado existen ventas con el mismo código `code_unique` pero que tienen otras configuraciones es decir unas tienen tallas otras no, otros color y así como se ve en el ejemplo se puede determinar cuantos `x` productos con `model, size, color` se han vendidos.

Comment: @Lobos Algo no entiendo si la tabla `tbl_order` no necesita saber las configuraciones ¿como se obtiene entonces el resultado deseado en tabla puesta de ejemplo al final?, como sabrá cuantos `X` productos se vendieron de la talla `X` y cuantos del mismo producto pero con la talla `XL` sino le pasamos esos parámetros como lo identificara.

Comment: Esos filtros se aplicarán a la tabla `tbl_stock_products` en el `where` de la consulta. Con esos filtros se podrá saber los `id_stock_products` que cumplen las condiciones y con esos `ids` se hará la relación a `tbl_order` para traer las ventas.

Comment: @Lobos Y, no es posible hacerlo si en el `WHERE` porque yo estoy creando una páginación tratando de listar todos los registros así como en el ejemplo del resultado deseado y, al agregar por `WHERE` no tendré registros sino le paso filtros, el único filtro que le quiero agregar es un buscador nada más.

Comment: @Lobos Oh bueno ya no entendí, me perdí pero aquí te dejo una imagen de lo que estoy tratando de conseguir el único problema que no cuadra es `vendidos` y `Stock` https://i.imgur.com/Cati7lM.png

Comment: Si quieres mostrar todos los registros es más sencillo, no necesitas el `where`. Como ya dijimos que cada registro de `tbl_stock_products` es una configuración y `tbl_order` es el detalle de ventas de esa configuración. Solo traes todos los registros de `tbl_order` asociados al `id_stock_product`.

Comment: @Lobos Puedes cambiar las configuraciones en el `SELECT` aquí https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q3iEtNW28frgwETSgVV6ZQ/3 por favor, es que no logro entender aún

Comment: Corrige el  script de creación porque no compila. La tabla `tbl_order` espera 15 valores y se le pasan 18.

Comment: @Lobos No se como corregirlo porque es su script de la anterior pregunta, en mi servidor funciona estoy usando la versión 5.2.0 pero en ese copilador no funciona y sale error en esta línea: `max(sp.item_total) over (PARTITION BY id_stock_product) AS item_total`

Comment: El error está en el `Schema SQL`, el editor del lado izquierdo. Borra la consulta del lado derecho y ejecútalo.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139897/discussion-between-lobos-and-j-mick).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Discusión](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62208319#62208319) para llegar a este resultado:

```
SELECT bo.establishment                                  AS office_establishment,
           bo.tradename                                      AS office_tradename,
           sp.code_unique,
           sp.model,
           sp.size,
           sp.color,
           MAX(sp.item_total)                                as item_total,
           sum(ifnull(odr.quantity, 0))                      as quantity,
           MAX(sp.item_total) - sum(ifnull(odr.quantity, 0)) as total
    FROM (
             select id_enterprise, id_branch_office, code_unique, model, size, color, sum(item_total) as item_total
             from tbl_stock_product
             group by id_enterprise, id_branch_office, code_unique, model, size, color
         ) sp
             LEFT JOIN tbl_access ac
                       ON sp.id_enterprise = ac.id_enterprise OR sp.id_branch_office = ac.id_branch_office
             LEFT JOIN tbl_enterprise ent ON sp.id_enterprise = ent.id_enterprise
             LEFT JOIN tbl_branch_office bo ON sp.id_branch_office = bo.id_branch_office
             LEFT JOIN tbl_order odr on concat(ifnull(odr.id_enterprise, ''), ifnull(odr.id_branch_office, ''),
                                               ifnull(odr.code_unique, ''), ifnull(odr.model, ''),
                                               ifnull(odr.size, ''),
                                               ifnull(odr.color, '')) =
                                        concat(ifnull(sp.id_enterprise, ''), ifnull(sp.id_branch_office, ''),
                                               ifnull(sp.code_unique, ''), ifnull(sp.model, ''),
                                               ifnull(sp.size, ''),
                                               ifnull(sp.color, ''))
    WHERE ac.id_user = 2
    GROUP BY bo.establishment, bo.tradename, sp.code_unique, sp.model, sp.size, sp.color;
```